How to generate Parent/Child columns from hierarchy in Excel
I need to translate a hierarchy in an Excel file, into Parent/Child Columns, using either a VBA script or column formulae.
e.g. This is the starting file, where the child is the first non-blank entry from left to right, and the parent is the first non-blank entry going up from 1 cell to the left of the child:

I need a way (VBA?) to translate columns D-I into columns B & C (and add col K as Col A)
So the output would be:

My biggest difficulty is with things like H6, 7 & 8 all having parent G5, and G5, 9 & 12 all having parent F4.
Steps (at least in my head, if using VBA - Although I might be confusing/over-complicating it):

Start at K3 (Root is only there as a parent for other entries)
Paste K3 into A3
Find the first non-blank entry from D3-I3 (E3 in this case) and copy/paste this into C3 (child)
From E3, come left 1 column, then find the first non-blank entry going upwards (D2) and copy paste that into B3 (parent)
Return to our starting point for that row (K3), move down 1 row and repeat until the end of the entries (Column K will never be blank until the list is exhausted)

If there is a formula-based way to do this, I am more than happy to use that, as it might be simpler to implement?
Thanks in advance.

Is is guaranteed that every entry on level n has a parent on level n-1? So consider in your example that row 5 is missing: Would parent of  A4 the value A2, is this invalid or is it guaranteed that is cannot happen in the input data?

Here are a set of formulas you can fill down, without VBA being necessary.  (These may not function in earlier versions of Excel)
All formulas will be written for entry into Row 3 of the workbook.
Column A is fairly simple:
=$K3

Columns B and C are a bit harder, and use the TAKE function, the TOCOL function, and the CHOOSECOLS function
Column B:
=TAKE(TOCOL(CHOOSECOLS($D$1:$I2, MATCH($C3, $D3:$I3, 0)-1), 3), -1)

Column C:
=TAKE(TOCOL($D3:$I3, 3), 1)

(An alternative for Column C could be =TEXTJOIN("", TRUE, $D3:$I3))
Column C just takes the current row, uses TOCOL to remove all Blank Cells or Error Values, and then returns the first remaining entry using TAKE.
Column B then looks at which column contains the value from Column C (using MATCH), takes the previous column (using CHOOSECOLS), and uses TOCOL to remove all Blank Cells or Error Values.  Then it returns the last remaining entry using TAKE (hence why it is -1: negative numbers count backwards from the end)
If you want to use these in VBA, you can set the Range.Formula, then Calculate the range (or worksheet), and finally set Range.Value = Range.Value to 'flatten' the data.

Thank you so much, Chronocidal.
I'll test it in the morning.
Really appreciate your help

Again.  Thank you so much.  Looks like I need to dig in to these particular Excel functions a bit more, as I've never seen them before.  That has saved me so much time.

A VBA solution.
Steps:

Read the data from column D:K into an 2D array
Build an empty 2D array (for output)
Loop over the data:

Whenever a value is found in the first 7 columns, save this data into a 1D array called parents.
If we are not at the first column (which is "root"), write the value into column 3 (child) and the parent of the next higher level to column 2 (parent).


When done, write the output array to your sheet.

Code is straight forward and looks like this:
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)   ' <-- Adapt to your needs
Dim inputData, outputData
' Count number of rows (we will skip the header row)
Dim rowCount As Long
rowCount = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Rows.Count - 1
' Read data
inputData = ws.Range("D2").Resize(rowCount, 8)
' Build output array
ReDim outputData(1 To rowCount, 1 To 3)
' Process the data row by row
Dim parents(1 To 7) As String
Dim row As Long, col As Long
For row = 1 To UBound(inputData)
    For col = 1 To 7
        If inputData(row, col) <> "" Then
            parents(col) = inputData(row, col)
            If col > 1 Then
                outputData(row, 1) = inputData(row, 8)      ' Type
                outputData(row, 2) = parents(col - 1)       ' Parent
                outputData(row, 3) = inputData(row, col)    ' Child
            End If
        End If
    Next col
Next row
' Write result into sheet
ws.Range("A2").Resize(rowCount, 3) = outputData


Thank FunThomas.
I'm going to test this in the morning, and thanks also for the excellent breakdown/explanation as well

Use End(xlUp) to locate the parent cell without needing to track the hierarchy or parent node.
Sub Demo()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, arrData, rngData As Range
    Set rngData = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    ' load table into array
    arrData = rngData.Value
    For i = LBound(arrData) + 2 To UBound(arrData)
        arrData(i, 1) = arrData(i, UBound(arrData, 2))
        For j = 0 To 5
            ' locate Child
            If Len(arrData(i, 4 + j)) > 0 Then
                arrData(i, 3) = arrData(i, 4 + j)
                ' locate Parent
                arrData(i, 2) = Cells(i, 3 + j).End(xlUp).Value
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
    Next i
    ' write output to sheet
    rngData.Value = arrData
End Sub


A clever alternative +:)
